# Java.awt.robot mousepress is not having any effect

Tags: java, awt, mouseevent, awtrobot, thread-sleep

I'm trying to simulate a left click in a different program using awt.robot, with the following code:

```
int mask = InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;
bot.mouseMove(x, y);   
bot.mousePress(mask);
bot.mouseRelease(mask);
```

While this is moving the mouse to the correct part of the screen, the other program doesn't seem to be receiving the click. What am I doing wrong?

In certain other programs, this same method produces the click, but in one program, it has no effect.

I have tried `Thread.sleep()` to wait 30-300 milliseconds between mouseMove and mousePress, but it had no effect.

Do I need to use JNI and native windows API to achieve this? I'm on Windows 8.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) *"I have tried `Thread.sleep()`"* Try instead [`delay(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#delay%28int%29), or [`setAutoWaitForIdle(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#setAutoWaitForIdle%28boolean%29)/[`waitForIdle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#waitForIdle%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong mask: `InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK`

Comment: Tried it, It has no effect either.

Comment: Its only in one particular program that the click is not being received, in another programs the same method is working. Mouse is being moved, but click has no effect.

Comment: Well, then I guess there is something conflicting or not compatible in the OS. I don't think you are doing anything wrong in your code. However, make sure that the other application has the focus. Maybe that is part of the problem. To enforce the focus, you might try clicking twice. However, be careful with that: clicking twice might perform two actions in the application.

Comment: Thanks, have tried clicking twice too but it had no effect either. I'm on Windows 8.

Comment: I ran out of inspiration. I'm sorry :)

Comment: Thanks anyway, have you ever worked with JNI or native windows mouse presses?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `bot.delay(n)` between `bot.mousePressed(mask)` and `bot.mouseReleased(mask)`?