# Performing a mouse click at a given x,y coordinate using JNA?

Tags: java, jna

How can I perform a left mouse click at a given mouse coordinate (x,y) using JNA? In particular, which library / class / package do I need to look into? I'm trying to do this in Windows 8 in particular. If necessary, I can get the title of the window.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have to use JNA? Mouse clicks can also be performed with the `Robot` class in the standard java API

Comment: @BackSlash Because of this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168945/java-awt-robot-mousepress-is-not-having-any-effect

Comment: Make sure you send a mouse down and a mouse up event with a pause in between.  Usually that's sufficient to simulate a mouse click, although your target application may very well be looking for some other event or event sequence.